# I want to create a gallery app using an grid view I ave over 300images that i want to import it from drawable. It is showing 33 frames skipped

Tags: android, multithreading, image, program-entry-point, frames

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.content.Context;

import android.widget.GridView;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context context;

public Integer [] images = { R.drawable.img_0,


        R.drawable.img_1, R.drawable.img_2,       R.drawable.img_41, R.drawable.img_42,     R.drawable.img_81,  R.drawable.img_82,     R.drawable.img_121, R.drawable.img_122,     R.drawable.img_161, R.drawable.img_162,      R.drawable.img_201, R.drawable.img_202,     R.drawable.img_241, R.drawable.img_242,     R.drawable.img_281, R.drawable.img_282,     R.drawable.img_321, R.drawable.img_322,
        R.drawable.img_3, R.drawable.img_4,      R.drawable.img_43, R.drawable.img_44,     R.drawable.img_83,  R.drawable.img_84,     R.drawable.img_123, R.drawable.img_124,     R.drawable.img_163, R.drawable.img_164,      R.drawable.img_203, R.drawable.img_204,     R.drawable.img_243, R.drawable.img_244,     R.drawable.img_283, R.drawable.img_284,     R.drawable.img_323,
        R.drawable.img_5, R.drawable.img_6,       R.drawable.img_45, R.drawable.img_46,     R.drawable.img_85,  R.drawable.img_86,     R.drawable.img_125, R.drawable.img_126,     R.drawable.img_165, R.drawable.img_166,      R.drawable.img_205, R.drawable.img_206,     R.drawable.img_245, R.drawable.img_246,     R.drawable.img_285, R.drawable.img_286,
        R.drawable.img_7, R.drawable.img_8,       R.drawable.img_47, R.drawable.img_48,     R.drawable.img_87,  R.drawable.img_88,     R.drawable.img_127, R.drawable.img_128,     R.drawable.img_167, R.drawable.img_168,      R.drawable.img_207, R.drawable.img_208,     R.drawable.img_247, R.drawable.img_248,     R.drawable.img_287, R.drawable.img_288,
        R.drawable.img_9, R.drawable.img_10,      R.drawable.img_49, R.drawable.img_50,     R.drawable.img_89,  R.drawable.img_90,     R.drawable.img_129, R.drawable.img_130,     R.drawable.img_169, R.drawable.img_170,      R.drawable.img_209, R.drawable.img_210,     R.drawable.img_249, R.drawable.img_250,     R.drawable.img_289, R.drawable.img_290,
        R.drawable.img_11, R.drawable.img_12,     R.drawable.img_51, R.drawable.img_52,     R.drawable.img_91,  R.drawable.img_92,     R.drawable.img_131, R.drawable.img_132,     R.drawable.img_171, R.drawable.img_172,      R.drawable.img_211, R.drawable.img_212,     R.drawable.img_251, R.drawable.img_252,     R.drawable.img_291, R.drawable.img_292,
        R.drawable.img_13, R.drawable.img_14,     R.drawable.img_53, R.drawable.img_54,     R.drawable.img_93,  R.drawable.img_94,     R.drawable.img_133, R.drawable.img_134,     R.drawable.img_173, R.drawable.img_174,      R.drawable.img_213, R.drawable.img_214,     R.drawable.img_253, R.drawable.img_254,     R.drawable.img_293, R.drawable.img_294,
        R.drawable.img_15, R.drawable.img_16,     R.drawable.img_55, R.drawable.img_56,     R.drawable.img_95,  R.drawable.img_96,     R.drawable.img_135, R.drawable.img_136,     R.drawable.img_175, R.drawable.img_176,      R.drawable.img_215, R.drawable.img_216,     R.drawable.img_255, R.drawable.img_256,     R.drawable.img_295, R.drawable.img_296,
        R.drawable.img_17, R.drawable.img_18,     R.drawable.img_57, R.drawable.img_58,     R.drawable.img_97,  R.drawable.img_98,     R.drawable.img_137, R.drawable.img_138,     R.drawable.img_177, R.drawable.img_178,      R.drawable.img_217, R.drawable.img_218,     R.drawable.img_257, R.drawable.img_258,     R.drawable.img_297, R.drawable.img_298,
        R.drawable.img_19, R.drawable.img_20,     R.drawable.img_59, R.drawable.img_60,     R.drawable.img_99,  R.drawable.img_100,    R.drawable.img_139, R.drawable.img_140,     R.drawable.img_179, R.drawable.img_180,      R.drawable.img_219, R.drawable.img_220,     R.drawable.img_259, R.drawable.img_260,     R.drawable.img_299, R.drawable.img_300,
        R.drawable.img_21, R.drawable.img_22,     R.drawable.img_61, R.drawable.img_62,     R.drawable.img_101, R.drawable.img_102,    R.drawable.img_141, R.drawable.img_142,     R.drawable.img_181, R.drawable.img_182,      R.drawable.img_221, R.drawable.img_222,     R.drawable.img_261, R.drawable.img_262,     R.drawable.img_301, R.drawable.img_302,
        R.drawable.img_23, R.drawable.img_24,     R.drawable.img_63, R.drawable.img_64,     R.drawable.img_103, R.drawable.img_104,    R.drawable.img_143, R.drawable.img_144,     R.drawable.img_183, R.drawable.img_184,      R.drawable.img_223, R.drawable.img_224,     R.drawable.img_263, R.drawable.img_264,     R.drawable.img_303, R.drawable.img_304,
        R.drawable.img_25, R.drawable.img_26,     R.drawable.img_65, R.drawable.img_66,     R.drawable.img_105, R.drawable.img_106,    R.drawable.img_145, R.drawable.img_146,     R.drawable.img_185, R.drawable.img_186,      R.drawable.img_225, R.drawable.img_226,     R.drawable.img_265, R.drawable.img_266,     R.drawable.img_305, R.drawable.img_306,
        R.drawable.img_27, R.drawable.img_28,     R.drawable.img_67, R.drawable.img_68,     R.drawable.img_107, R.drawable.img_108,    R.drawable.img_147, R.drawable.img_148,     R.drawable.img_187, R.drawable.img_188,      R.drawable.img_227, R.drawable.img_228,     R.drawable.img_267, R.drawable.img_268,     R.drawable.img_307, R.drawable.img_308,
        R.drawable.img_29, R.drawable.img_30,     R.drawable.img_69, R.drawable.img_70,     R.drawable.img_109, R.drawable.img_110,    R.drawable.img_149, R.drawable.img_150,     R.drawable.img_189, R.drawable.img_190,      R.drawable.img_229, R.drawable.img_230,     R.drawable.img_269, R.drawable.img_270,     R.drawable.img_309, R.drawable.img_310,
        R.drawable.img_31, R.drawable.img_32,     R.drawable.img_71, R.drawable.img_72,     R.drawable.img_111, R.drawable.img_112,    R.drawable.img_151, R.drawable.img_152,     R.drawable.img_191, R.drawable.img_192,      R.drawable.img_231, R.drawable.img_232,     R.drawable.img_271, R.drawable.img_272,     R.drawable.img_311, R.drawable.img_312,
        R.drawable.img_33, R.drawable.img_34,     R.drawable.img_73, R.drawable.img_74,     R.drawable.img_113, R.drawable.img_114,    R.drawable.img_153, R.drawable.img_154,     R.drawable.img_193, R.drawable.img_194,      R.drawable.img_233, R.drawable.img_234,     R.drawable.img_273, R.drawable.img_274,     R.drawable.img_313, R.drawable.img_314,
        R.drawable.img_35, R.drawable.img_36,     R.drawable.img_75, R.drawable.img_76,     R.drawable.img_115, R.drawable.img_116,    R.drawable.img_155, R.drawable.img_156,     R.drawable.img_195, R.drawable.img_196,      R.drawable.img_235, R.drawable.img_236,     R.drawable.img_275, R.drawable.img_276,     R.drawable.img_315, R.drawable.img_316,
        R.drawable.img_37, R.drawable.img_38,     R.drawable.img_77, R.drawable.img_78,     R.drawable.img_117, R.drawable.img_118,    R.drawable.img_157, R.drawable.img_158,     R.drawable.img_197, R.drawable.img_198,      R.drawable.img_237, R.drawable.img_238,     R.drawable.img_277, R.drawable.img_278,     R.drawable.img_317, R.drawable.img_318,
        R.drawable.img_39, R.drawable.img_40,     R.drawable.img_79, R.drawable.img_80,     R.drawable.img_119, R.drawable.img_120,    R.drawable.img_159, R.drawable.img_160,     R.drawable.img_199, R.drawable.img_200,      R.drawable.img_239, R.drawable.img_240,     R.drawable.img_279, R.drawable.img_280,     R.drawable.img_319, R.drawable.img_320,

};

public ImageAdapter(Context c){

    context = c;
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240,240));
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: For a few images, just loading resources on the main application thread may be fine, but not for hundreds. You may need to look into using an [image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), that can load those images on background threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not good, storing 300 images in drawable folder. It makes your apk larger. Put your images in any server, and then get links with json and then set your images in imageview's. You can use these libraries for loading images and caching: [Picasso by square](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide by Bumptech](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This libraries help you for loading images easily, cropping, fitting and caching.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suggest is using `getResources().getIdentifier()` instead of hard-coding resource identifiers like that.  Probably outside scope of this question but would also recommend using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: "First thing I'd suggest is using getResources().getIdentifier() instead of hard-coding resource identifiers like that." -- that will make performance worse, not better.